# How can I reshape a wide dataset into a long dataset using multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, reshape

I have a dataframe that I need to reshape

```
ID Treatment Dog_Weight Cat_Weight Horse_Weight Pig_Weight
1     A         20         10          100         1000 
2     A         30         20          200         550
3     A         40         30          300         750
4     A         50         40          400         800
5     B         60         50          500         650
6     B         70         60          600         450
7     B         80         70          700         500
8     B         90         80          800         600
```

I am trying to get it so it looks like this:

```
    ID  Animal  Animal_Weight_A Animal_Weight_B
0   1    Dog         20            60
1   2    Dog         30            70
2   3    Dog         40            80
3   4    Dog         50            90
4   1    Cat         10            50
5   2    Cat         20            60
6   3    Cat         30            70
7   4    Cat         40            80
8   1    Horse      100            500
9   2    Horse      200            600
10  3    Horse      300            700
11  4    Horse      400            800
12  1    Pig        1000           650
13  2    Pig        550            450
14  3    Pig        750            500
15  4    Pig        800            600
```

I have been able to do so using the following steps:

1. Groupby to get aggregate information for each animal:

```
df_test1 = (
    df.groupby(["ID", "Treatment"])[
        "Dog_Weight", "Cat_Weight", "Horse_Weight", "Pig_Weight"
    ]
    .mean()
    .reset_index()
)
```

2. Melt data to get animal into columns:

```
df_test2 = pd.melt(
    df_test1,
    id_vars=["ID", "Treatment"],
    value_vars=["Dog_Weight", "Cat_Weight", "Horse_Weight", "Pig_Weight"],
).rename(columns={"variable": "Animal", "value": "Animal_Weight"})
```

3. Extract animal name

```
df_test2["Animal"] = df_test2["Animal"].str.split("_").str[0]
```

4. Separate by Treatment

```
test_A = df_test2.query("Treatment == 'A'")
test_B = df_test2.query("Treatment == 'B'")
```

5. Merge on ID and Animal to get datasets back together, drop unnecessary columns

```
df_testfinal = pd.merge(
    test_A,
    test_B,
    on=["ID", "Animal"],
    suffixes=("_A", "_B"),
).drop(["Treatment_A", "Treatment_B"], axis=1)
```

While this method works, it seems like there is probably a way this can be done using reshape/pivot/melt. I was hoping someone might be able to help me find a way to do that using one of those methods or reducing the number of steps?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try melt first, then pivot:

```
tmp = df.melt(['ID','Treatment'], var_name='Animal')
tmp['Animal'] = tmp['Animal'].str.extract('^([^_]+)')
tmp['ID'] = tmp.groupby(['Animal','Treatment']).cumcount()

out = (tmp.pivot_table(index=['Animal','ID'], columns=['Treatment'], 
                      values='value')
       .add_prefix('Animal_Weight_').reset_index()
      )
```

Output:

```
Treatment Animal  ID  Animal_Weight_A  Animal_Weight_B
0            Cat   0               10               50
1            Cat   1               20               60
2            Cat   2               30               70
3            Cat   3               40               80
4            Dog   0               20               60
5            Dog   1               30               70
6            Dog   2               40               80
7            Dog   3               50               90
8          Horse   0              100              500
9          Horse   1              200              600
10         Horse   2              300              700
11         Horse   3              400              800
12           Pig   0             1000              650
13           Pig   1              550              450
14           Pig   2              750              500
15           Pig   3              800              600
```